Derivation of the ideal gas law, reasoning for multiplicity
In Reichl's "A modern course in statistical mechanics", for the derivation of the ideal gas law:
We derive the expression:
$$M_N(E)=\frac{V^N(2\pi mE)^{3N/2}}{N! h^{3N}(3N/2)!}$$
Now, this is the number of states an ideal gas can be in with energy less than or equal to $E$. But to derive the entropy we want an expression for the number of states with just energy $E$. Reichl argues that the two expressions (the one for the number of states less than or equal to the energy and the one for states corresponding to the energy) are the same to a good approximation for a system with large degrees of freedom.
Her argument is as follows:
The total phase space volume of the gas is denoted by $\Omega^{D}(E)$. Now, divide this volume into a sequence of energy shells each with width $\Delta$E, the volume of this shell is denoted by $\Omega_{\Delta E}(E)$. According to her the volume of this shell $\Omega_{\Delta E}(E)$ is the volume of the phase space corresponding to the states with energy $E$. I don't understand the highlighted argument.
After this she shows that the logarithms of both $\Omega^{(D)}(E)$ and $\Omega_{\Delta E}(E)$ converge to the same value, but that is not related to the question.

I will just tweak the notation slightly for clarity. Let $\Omega_<(E)$ be the region of phase space where the energy is at most $E$, i.e. states of energy $E'$ st $E'<E$. Your original $\Omega^D$ is its volume (I think, not sure of the "total"), that I will rather name:
$$
W_<(E) = |\Omega_<(E)|
$$
Classically, it is proportional to your $M_N$. Let $\Omega_{\Delta E}(E)$ be the region of phase space where energy is in the bound $(E-\Delta E,E)$, i.e. stets of energy $E'$ st $E-\Delta E < E' < E$ with the corresponding volume:
$$
W(E) = |\Omega_{\Delta E}(E)|
$$
The argument is to prove that:
$$
W(E)\asymp W_<(E)
$$
the former being what you want and the latter being what you have calculated. By inclusion, you already know that:
$$
W(E)<W_<(E)
$$
In the case of an ideal gas, this might seem paradoxical. $\Omega_<$ is a ball (disregarding the common factor due to the real space volume), so it would mean that the entire ball's volume is essentially concentrated at a narrow shell about its boundary. The key assumption is that this holds in the thermodynamic limit, i.e. infinite dimensional phase space.
To prove it, you will need to do the math that you alluded to in your last sentence, as the result is highly counter intuitive. It's related to the fact that the volume of a ball inscribed in a cube has a negligible volume in high dimensions and other similar paradoxes (like in here: "Thinking outside the 10-dimensional box"). Essentially there is "more room" than expected away from the origin. You can start to get a feel of this concentration to the edge in the case of the sphere with some simple calculations. An inner boundary shell of thickness $h$ of the a unit ball in $D$ dimensions has relative volume:
$$
V = 1-(1-h)^D
$$
For fixed $h$ as $D\to\infty$, the relative volume does tend to $1$, no matter how small $h$ is. You can already start to see the trend in the familiar lower dimensions $D=1,2,3$. This illustrates the typical concentration effect in high dimensions. The calculations you are alluding to in the last line essentially boil down to this simple observation.

Thank you, just to clarify, you mean $\Omega^{(D)}(E)$ instead of $M_N$ in the first paragraph of your answer right ? Because $M_N$ is just the multiplicity...the number of states with energy less than equal to $E$.

Also, why does the shell, with energy in the bounds $(E-\Delta E,E )$ have states with just energy E ? I would assume they would have states with energies from $E-\Delta E$ to $E$.

I've edited my answer for clarity, but I don't get your second comment. Yes the states of energy exactly $E$ is the boundary of the shell, but in some sense it is infinitesimally thin, so you need to add a "thickness" to it.

Do you mean that the thickness $\Delta E$ is very small in comparison to $E$ ?

Also, the book refers to a sequence of shells and not a single shell. Do you know why that is the case?

Just to clarify my previous comment a bit, but $h=\Delta E$ right ?
